# WinRT/Metro/Win8 Share Contracts - How to send mail with subject, text and attachtment?

Tags: email, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

Is there an build in feature that provides sharing multiply types like text and image to other applications? All i found was sharing only text or only images to the build in mail application of windows 8.

Want to send an E-Mail were the subject, text and attachment is preset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, the current build of Mail (Release Preview) simply won't do it.  If you have an attachment, it ignores the subject and text.  Look like we're going to have to wait for RTM or test with another email client.

**UPDATE:**  AFAIK, this is still the case even after RTM.  The Mail client simply can't handle both a message body and an attachment.

Comment: Thanks so far thats exactly the same i found out and what i heared from microsoft till now. Lets hope they release the RTM soon, which is hopefully going to provide that functionallity.

Comment: This is still the case even months after the release of the OS. This is a pretty big oversight on Microsoft's part, considering they did away with any other means of programmatically creating an email (with the "mailto" method being inadequate).